# How to add postman body form data in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Hi im new to jmeter and wanted to check performance of api in jmeter but not sure how to use form data as im using video in my api not sure how to add and test

Postman : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJrKN.png)

it would be helpful if some one helps
thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try? it's in HTTP request Parameters tab

Answer (score 0):

The easiest conversion option is just recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)

1. Start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. If you're using [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocol - [import JMeter's self-signed certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/)

   [image]
4. Copy the file `facial_10sec.webm` file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation, [this way JMeter will be able to properly intercept the request and generate the request body](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)
5. Run your request in Postman
6. JMeter will capture the request and generate the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and the HTTP Header Manager

Answer (score 0):

Postman Integration is demonstrated in [this short video](https://youtu.be/s5UJq2RlwBc)

It does not have the HTTPS Certificate integration. If you are using HTTPS, please import the JMeter CA certificate into the Postman.